# Grep filename with unknown name

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Using Ubuntu Linux i want to find a file but the exactly filename is unknown.

All i know is that the filename is verify..something and has the .php extension.

I try `grep verify /home/myuser` but did not find

Comment: where's the file located?

Comment: at /home/myuser but i have several subdirectories and want to analise each of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this from current directory if name starts with `verify` and ends with `.php`:

```
find . -iname 'verify*.php'
```

Comment: how can this search be recursive? to search inside subdirectories ?

Comment: Recursive is `find`'s default.

Comment: And find manpage says `but the match is case insensitive`. In this case the search  will match `VerifYsomesuff.php` as well as `VERIFYsomesuff.php`